# Microsoft Excel- Auto-populate data into a new sheet based on specific text

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft

I am trying to get excel to copy and paste the entire row from one sheet to a new sheet when a specific text is input into one cell of that row. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Copy and paste", no, not without VBA. But you could set something up with lookups that might serve your purpose. Show us what ya got and let's find out.

Answer (score 0):

Create a sample enter the formula in L1 then drag and drop to right:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$5=$K$2)*($B$1:$G$1=L1),$B$2:$G$5)
```

[image]